# How can I iterate over all of my functions in JavaScript and add try catch blocks?

Tags: javascript, onerror

I'm trying to write to a global error handler that can work in Chrome and Safari. WebKit browsers don't support `window.onerror`, so I'd like to find a way to iterate through all of the functions in my code and encapsulate them in `try - catch` blocks, passing any exceptions to my custom error handling code. Does anyone know of an effective way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have to question why you want to catch ALL methods. Perhaps you should restrict the scope of what needs error handling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery aop](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-aop/). Something like

```
jQuery.aop.around( {target: window, method: /.*/}, 
  function(invocation) {
    var result;
    try{
      result = invocation.proceed(); 
    }
    catch( e ){
      myHandler();
    }
    return result;
  }
);
```

And in case you're unused to AOP, [here's the wiki explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).

Comment: Cool! I never knew about that.